# How to do transparent the launch image slowly.(alpha = 0.0;)

Tags: iphone, image, ios-simulator

I can see  the launch image(png at the root of the project, sized:320x480 pixels)  on the iPhone simulator and iPhone device.
And then,I want to do transparent it(the launch image) slowly .(alpha = 0.0;) 
But I cannot do it.though I tried variously.

Thank you,
  Katsumi

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at UIView animation methods. Method like animateWithDuartion should be sufficient for your goal. Your fade-out animation in the simplest implementation will looks like following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^(void){self.splashImage.alpha = 0.0f;}];
```

Comment: I'm sorry that my answer is delayed. 
Thank you for your answer.But, I cannot solve the problem yet.
I think impossible the fade-out animation if the launch image was set in "Info.plist". 
Therefore, I made the class for the launch image (UIViewControllerSubclass(with XIB)) .
The screen is done the fade-out animation,and throw it on the main window. 
Then, the button of the MainWindow becomes invalid.
I want to do transparent the launch image ,then I want to do effective the button of the screen.
Thank you,   Katsumi

Comment: You are right that you created separate view hierarchy that contains your image and applied animation to it. However, I do not understand your issues with a button. Could you elaborate this case a little bit?

Comment: Ms Leonov
Thank you for a very kind answer. 
I was trying for a long time by my program(TabBar Base).
However, I succeeded when I tested the fade-out by a simple program. 
I will think for a moment.
Thank you very much.
Katsumi

Answer (score 0):

When the app launches you'll have to immediately create a new instance of the image via `UIImageView` and throw it on the main window. Then once you get access to that `UIView` you can use basic animation techniques to fade it out, such as `-animateWithDuration:animations:`.

Of course you'll want to setup some type of view below this, so you have your main app's content available right away.

---

Code sample:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // PLACE YOUR APP LAUNCH CODE HERE

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]];
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        imageView.alpha = 0.0;
        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    }];


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that my answer is delayed. 
Thank you for your answer.But, I cannot solve the problem yet.
I think impossible the fade-out animation if the launch image was set in "Info.plist". 
Therefore, I made the class for the launch image (UIViewControllerSubclass(with XIB)) .
The screen is done the fade-out animation,and throw it on the main window. 
Then, the button of the MainWindow becomes invalid.
I want to do transparent the launch image ,then I want to do effective the button of the screen.
Thank you,   Katsumi

Comment: K you make no sense, and thanks for the same cookie-cutter response as the other answer. Just make a UIImageView, set the image to the same image as your launch image, add it as a direct subview of your UIWindow *ABOVE* all other views immediately upon launch. then just use the runloop via UIView animations to change the alpha, and finally just release the imageview. its *not that hard*

Comment: Mr Sullivan
Thank you very much for your early answer. 
The "cookie-cutter response" was impolite as you said. 
I am so sorry. 
It has already tried as you say. 
（I might be doing a possibly wrong method. Because I am a beginner developer.）
I tried from the beginning by my program(TabBar Base).
 It worked well when trying as you said by a simple program.
I will work a little more. 
I wish to express my gratitude to you. 

Katsumi